# How to make explorer.exe act normal while it launches a file at startup?

Tags: boot, windows-explorer, virus

I want to infect "explorer.exe" file: everytime is launched, first, it should do a "START SomeProgram.exe" or other commands, then act like normal (more like a virus).
I want to see if there can be alternative ways of executing programs at startup, but without causing damage and being silent, without using registry keys or moving to "Startup" folder (I know it might be detected by antiviruses, but I don't care about that).
I want to make it keep the parameters too. E. g.: If "explorer.exe" is called with "C:\Folder\Other Folder" parameter, it should still open the path as normal. Any way to infect it?

Comment: What I try to do is to inject the "explorer.exe" file, making it run my code, and then return to original one. The problem is that I don't know how to do that... I found this website: (http://www2.inf.fh-bonn-rhein-sieg.de/~ikarim2s/how2injectcode/code_inject.html), but I cannot find any "CaveCode" in some test executable I choosed.

Comment: This seems out of my realm of knowledge but here's this link in case you find it of any usefulness: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg314982(v=vs.85).aspx